# Which part of code would be rendered as virtual DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, vue.js, virtual-dom

I'm newbie in virtual DOM topic and last days I've been thinking of how it should work.

Let's imagine that I have a simple template engine in my project, for instance twig. And I'm using vue.js as a javascript framework.
So I could build the following page:

```
<div id="app">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="item in items">{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>
    <component><component/>
</div>

<template id="component">
      <div class="center-xs">
          <div class="row">
               <div class="col-xs-12">
                   Some text
               </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</template>

<script>
   Vue.component('component', {
       template: '#component'
   });
   var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            items: ['item1', 'item2']
        }
    });
</script>
```

Which part of code would be Virtual DOM:

- a. Nothing
- b. Everything inside of `#app`
- c. `Items` and `component`
- d. Only `component`

And why? It'd great if share with me any info (links, your thoughts, official docs).

Thank u!

Comment: have you done any research/googling?

Comment: @Cruiser yes, I have

Answer (score 0):

The code in the `<div id=app>` (e.g.`<p> <ul>`) is not DOM it is HTML markup that the browser then parses and then renders as its DOM.  Since there is existing html code in the #app element it will be included by Vue as part of its template and thus be part of the Virtual DOM. Though technically since the `<p>` element never has any Vue operations performed on it, it is ignored.

If you have Vue Devtools extension installed in your browser you can see the representation of the Virtual DOM  in the components view.  `<ROOT>`  will be your #app div of course, and then you will only see any `<components>` there, not the `<p>` element or even the `<ul><li>` elements.

It is a good practice to never have any html markup at all or otherwise component tags in your root element. Simply`<div id='app'></div>` then have all the other elements rendered exclusively by Vue through the Virtual DOM. This is achieved simply through the `render` function.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
   TopLevelComponent
  },
  render: function(createElement) {
    return createElement(TopLevelComponent);
  }
})
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Virtual-DOM

Comment: What about when I need to have some html inside of #app? Or everything inside of root element in vue should be Virtual Dom? P.S. It is not necessary to have SPA for me, I need some features from vue, however not all logic of site. And there is no chance to use devtools when using vue from CDN.

Comment: P.P.S. And of course, I meant the DOM which would be rendered by browser. I've changed the title to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: I said it is "good practice" to avoid markup in your root element.  In practice a tiny amount probably won't hurt.  The trouble is the browser will parse the markup but 'choke' on anything that it does not recognize.   In an instance similar to your example where  you have a `<table>` but instead of having the `<tr>` a component renders the `<tr>` dynamically you will experience the problem.   Example `<table><v-my-tr></v-my-tr></table>` may be rendered in the DOM by the browser as `<v-my-tr></v-my-tr> <table></table>` since it does not recognize the inner element as a valid markup.

Comment: You can still use the render function or v-html etc to include the html in the root so there is no reason you can't follow good practice.   
-------
Also I am fairly certain, have not tried it, but I believe you can use Vue Devtools with Vue from a CDN, just not a "production" or minified version.  (Such as this one https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js)   See the documentation here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CDN